# c# listbox item size limit

Tags: c#

When I add an item to a listbox in c#, if the string is > 4680 characters it displays as a blank line. I can still access the entire string from within the program.

Did I run up against a limit or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of text in a textbox is 64 KB worth of text. [Here ya go.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997541.aspx)

Comment: What is the solution? is there anything to increase the size of a list box?

Comment: That article on the link is ancient. Are you sure the information it gives is valid to modern computers and Operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

displaying 4680+ characters for a single list item is not useful for the end user. You need to truncate the text or find another way to reference the text that is more user friendly.

Comment: I don't disagree. I inherited this program (my first experience with c#) and was asked why it wasn't displaying some lines.